# How to replace the text "Ref:" to "SKU" under each of product pages on my site?

Tags: product, custom-attributes

Somebody please help me to change the text "Ref:" to "SKU" just before the product code showing at each of the product pages on my magento site. My developer is unable to locate the input page or location of "Ref:" text within the whole system. Please help!

Sample page link: http://dewstem.com/index.php/special-sentiments.html

Answer (score 1):

You can turn ON template path hints in your admin.

Please follow the give URL:
https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21255937-How-do-I-turn-on-template-path-hints-

**Note:** If your store is live make sure to enable the hints only for your IP address.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in app/design/frontend/default/[yourtheme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

If you do a control+find in there you should find 'Ref'

Alternatively in a terminal do something like

```
grep -rnw . -e 'Ref:'
```

and you should see the file location